# Convert Sql Statement to Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, linq

How can i convert this sql query to linq in entity framework core ?

```sql
Select a.Id,a.Url,c.Title,a.ParentId,b.totalSubCats 
From [Tbl_Menu] As a 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
  ( Select ParentId, Count(*) As totalSubCats From [Tbl_Menu] Group By ParentId ) As b
On a.Id=b.ParentId
LEFT OUTER JOIN [Tbl_Menu] As c On a.Id = c.Id
ORDER BY a.Id
```

And we have this columns in `Menu_Tbl`

`Id` , `Url` , `Title` , `Description` , `ParentId`

For `Left Join` I wrote this query but can`t run

```
 var query = (from m1 in _context.Menu_Tbl 
                     join m2 in _context.Menu_Tbl on m1.Id equals m2.Id 
                     into m3 from m in m3.DefaultIfEmpty() select m1);
```

Comment: Have you read [ask]? Show what you have tried, Stack Overflow is not a code translation service.

Comment: Show what you have tried. And to the upvoter: I hope they take your voting rights away.

Comment: I'm definitely here to help, try checking my profile. Again, you need to read [ask]. There are certain things that we expect of askers, and you show none. If your code "can't run", explain what happens. Doesn't it compile, does it throw a runtime exception? What did you find when you researched those errors?

Comment: @CodeCaster Everything necessary was done. I have a sql query that needs to be rewritten to an entity. I have included in my question what I have done in the project.

Comment: SQL queries can't be converted to LINQ. At best you can write a LINQ statement that is translated into similar SQL. That requires knowledge of the class model and the mappings because navigation properties should be used and not LINQ's `join` statement. That's why this question lacks background info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one should work. Just divide big query by small pieces (subqueries)

```cs
var grouped = 
   from m in ctx.Tbl_Menu
   group m by new { m.ParentId } into g
   select new 
   {
       g.Key.ParentId,
       totalSubCats = g.Count()
   };

var query = 
   from a in ctx.Tbl_Menu 
   join b in grouped on a.Id equals b.ParentId into gj
   from b in gj.DefaultIfEmpty()
   join c in ctx.Tbl_Menu on a.Id equals c.Id into ggj
   from c in ggj.DefaultIfEmpty()
   select new 
   {
       a.Id,
       a.Url,
       c.Title,
       a.ParentId,
       b.totalSubCats 
   };
```

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work and has many errors

Comment: So, you have not posted model and want something working without errors? Fixed grouping.

Comment: Thanks, it worked good. just i change `gj` to `ggj` because it was repeated.

Comment: Writing from the memory, so mistakes are possible. Corrected answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be easier to just make that query a stored procedure and then call the stored procedure using yourReturnedDbSet objectReceived = context.yourReturnedDbSet.FromSqlRaw("EXECUTE StoredProcedureName @exampleParam"). But as for converting it you can pretty much use the same syntax if you have the correct objects. You will also need a list that holds the type you are being returned.

Comment: I am using Entity Framework Core and there is no good routine support  for Stored Procedure

Comment: I am not sure what you mean, I am using stored procedures with EFCore and it is fine. You just need to create a new DbSet sometimes.

Comment: Bad idea. Query is simple and creating SP is an overkill.

Comment: On the contrary, I think stored procedures are pretty easy to make as well.

Comment: I think the `dataset` creates extra load on your server. Especially for systems with a large number of users. A `dataset` will be created for each user. It means initial many `dataset` for many users.

Comment: @MatthewJackson, very easy? Create stored proc, create migration, maintain.

Comment: Not true, SP's cache your execution so multiple calls are considerably faster. Also, you are still receiving an object back for each user from your linq so the extra load comment is not applicable. And you have to restart your server with any change to the linq query in the future.